# WPF Getting the content of a ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls, listviewitem

I have a school assignment: when a ListViewItem gets double-clicked, it's content has to be displayed in the MessageBox. I've done quite a lot of research on the internet and couldn't find a fitting solution to my problem. What is the easiest way to get the content of a ListViewItem?

The ListView looks like this:

```
<ListView Name="LV">
    <ListViewItem>a listview</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem >with several</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>items</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have explictly assigned ListViewItem instances to the ListView (as in the example in the question), you can get each ListViewItem's content by means of its `Content` property.

You may access it in a `MouseDoubleClick` event handler.

```
<ListView x:Name="LV" MouseDoubleClick="LV_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListViewItem>a listview</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>with several</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>items</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

The event handler in code behind:

```
private void LV_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (ListViewItem)LV.SelectedItem;
    var content = (string)item.Content;

    MessageBox.Show(content);
}
```

---

There is however a better way to get the `Content` of the `SelectedItem`.

Set the `SelectedValuePath` property

```
<ListView x:Name="LV" MouseDoubleClick="LV_MouseDoubleClick"
          SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ListViewItem>a listview</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>with several</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>items</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

and get `SelectedValue` in code behind:

```
private void LV_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var content = (string)LV.SelectedValue;

    MessageBox.Show(content);
}
```

---

As a note, your ListView should be a ListBox, the base class of ListView. You would only use a ListView when you also set its `View` property.

Comment: If I use the second option you have provided, the message box that appears is empty. If using the first option, however, I get the following exception when running the app: **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**

**item was null.**

Comment: Not sure what exactly you did, but both examples are working fine for me. The first click selects an item, the second click invokes the event handler.